# Синонимы терминов информатики

Tags: синонимы

Есть ли синонимы у терминов информатики?
контексто-зависимая грамматика = ...  стек = ...  веер = ...

Answer (score 1):

Не советую искать синонимы.

Специалисты не поймут, ученикам лучше сразу привыкать к жаргону, а прочим - ни к чему.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Данный вопрос стоит у меня в контрольной работе, не подскажите,  как на него ответить?

Comment: Из всего перечисленного могу прокомментировать только "стек". Это "пирамида".

Что такое "веер" - вообще не понял, а "контекстно-ориентированная грамматика" - слишком громоздкое понятие для синонима.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за ответ)

Comment: По поводу "веера".. Возможно, имелся ввиду "бип" ("Beep" латинскими буквами) - тогда это "гудок".

Answer (score 0):

В информатике не очень разбираюсь, но как лингвист могу сказать, что   контекстно-ориентированная грамматика - это контекстно-зависимая грамматика

А судя по сайту:
http://www.codenet.ru/progr/alg/cmp/004.php   
(Класс контекстно-свободных языков допускает распознавание  с
помощью недетерминированного КА со  стековой  (или  магазинной)
памятью)  стек - это магазин.

Вот ещё нашла:

Веер - то же, что и "звездный граф",полный двудольный граф (Complete bipartite graph) — двудольный граф, у которого любые две вершины, входящие в разные доли,смежны.( Евстигнеев В.А., Касьянов В.Н. Словарь по графам в информатике)
 Звездный граф (Starred graph) — полный двудольный граф

А почему у Вас в названии грамматический род синонимов?

Comment: нужно смотреть в словарях математического языка

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за ответ) очень выручили)

Comment: @Людмила "Стек" - последовательно организованная память с доступом "первый вошёл - последний вышел" (данные добавляются в конец "стека" и извлекаются тоже с конца).

Наиболее близкий аналог в "реале" - пирамида (элементы добавляются на вершину, и с вершины снимаются). Кстати, точка доступа к "стеку" называется "топ" ("вершина").

Comment: greydog, спасибо за лекцию, я в курсе:  Стек (англ. stack — стопка) — структура данных с методом доступа к элементам LIFO (англ. Last In — First Out, «последним пришел — первым вышел»). Чаще всего принцип работы стека сравнивают со стопкой тарелок: чтобы взять вторую сверху, нужно взять верхнюю. http://wiki-linki.ru/Page/13513  НО: В информатике: советское название стека - МАГАЗИН :http://wiki-linki.ru/Citates/13513 
Так что я не фантазирую, стек-это магазин

Answer (score 0):

контекст**н**о-зависимая грамматика = КЗ-грамматика. Другого не знаю.

стек = ... ?? стек и есть. Не знаю синонимов. Пирамида никаким богом тут не подходит. Разве что детская пирамидка. Магазин - возможно. Был такой термин, но настолько давно, что я уже и не соображу, что он значил на заре кибернетики. Возможно, что и некий аналог стека.

веер = не знаю термина, подозреваю что это "ненаправленный граф без циклов в котором существует хотя бы одна вершина, для которой все прочие вершины соединены с ней хотя бы одним ребром". Какой тут может быть синоним - не представляю.

Вообще это не по русскому языку вопрос...